# When is the Duckworth-Lewis method applied?

Tags: cricket, duckworth-lewis

I've read a minimal amount about this in some of the questions which have been posted already here and the posts which were linked. However, I'm still unsure if the Duckworth-Lewis method is applied in the following scenarios:

1. When the rain interrupts in the middle of the first innings of a 50 over match?
2. When the rain interrupts once the first innings is complete?
3. When the rain interrupts once the second team has batted a certain number of overs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the Duckworth-Lewis method would be applied in all three scenarios. The only scenario in which a rain-shortened match does *not* have the Duckworth-Lewis method applied is if the match is shortened *before* the start of the first team's innings, as in that case both teams are equally aware of the number of overs they will face before starting their innings.